# Обрезка видео android по длительности

Tags: java, android, видео

Мне нужно выбрать видео с галереи и если оно больше 10 секунд обрезать. Возможно есть какие то библиотеки, и есть пример кода где реализована обрезка видео по длине от начала до заданой секунды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам библиотечка: [github.com/sannies/mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser)

Вот вам пример: [example](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/ShortenExample.java)

> On Android 4.1 you can access the hardware codecs via MediaCodec API
>   which could be an option (but I haven't seen any example of that yet)

[из ответа на подобный вопрос, но очень старый](http://%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20(%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9))

Answer (score 0):

Нашел библиотеку которая уже работает с m4parser и есть своя вьюха, кому пригодиться держите - https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer